# How to remove current record when click on remove button

Tags: angularjs

I am new at Angular.js. I am looking to do some dynamic table creation. I added some records helping with JSON Ang ng-model but how can I remove current record when click on remove button?

Passing with this operator:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.emplist = [
                      {empname:'samudrala',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 450'},
                      {empname:'soujanya',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 451'},
                      {empname:'suguna',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 452'},
                      {empname:'sangeetha',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 453'},
                      {empname:'sadhanandham',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 454'},
                      {empname:'jai',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 455'},
                      {empname:'vijay',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 456'},
                      {empname:'Ajay',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 457'},
                      {empname:'Sandya',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 458'},
                      {empname:'Raamu',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 459'}
                      ];
    $scope.addItem = function(){
        $scope.emplist.push({'empname':$scope.empname,'empsalary':$scope.empsalary,'empid':$scope.empid});
        $scope.empname = '';
        $scope.empsalary = '';
        $scope.empid = '';
    }
    $scope.remItem = function(x){
        $scope.emplist.splice(x,1);
    }
});
```

```css
body{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color:#333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE Html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table style="width:100%;">
<tr height="25" style=" background: #99ff00;">
<th width="5%"></th>
<th width="40%">EMP Name</th>
<th width="30%">EMP Salary</th>
<th width="25%">EMP ID</th>
</tr>
<tr height="25" ng-repeat="x in emplist">
<td style="text-align: center; background: #99ff00;" ng-if="$odd" >{{$index}}</td>
<td style="text-align: center; background: #00ff00;" ng-if="$even" >{{$index}}</td>
<td style="text-align: center; background: #99ff00;" ng-if="$odd" >{{x.empname}}</td>
<td style="text-align: center; background: #00ff00;" ng-if="$even" >{{x.empname}}</td>
<td style="text-align: center; background: #99ff00;" ng-if="$odd">{{x.empsalary}}</td>
<td style="text-align: center; background: #00ff00;" ng-if="$even">{{x.empsalary}}</td>
<td style="text-align: center; background: #99ff00;" ng-if="$odd">{{x.empid}}  <button ng-click="remItem();" style="background:#00ffff; border:0px;">&times; Remove</button></td>
<td style="text-align: center; background: #00ff00;" ng-if="$even">{{x.empid}} <button ng-click="remItem();" style="background:#00ffff; border:0px;">&times; Remove</button></td>
</tr>
<tr height="25">
<td><button ng-click="addItem();" style="background: #00ffff; border:0px; width:100%; height:100%;">Add</button></td>
<td style="padding:2px;"><input type="text" ng-model="empname" style="width:100%;" ></td>
<td style="padding:2px;"><input type="text" ng-model="empsalary" style="width:100%;" ></td>
<td style="padding:2px;"><input type="text" ng-model="empid" style="width:100%;" ></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of showing the table row for each record, use ng-repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat="emp in emplist">
  <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
  <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
  <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
  <td><button ng-click="remItem($index)">Remove</button></td>
```

And inside the controller directly you can get the $index

```
$scope.remItem = function(itemIndex){
  $scope.emplist.splice(itemIndex,1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Pass Current Index in your function

```
<button ng-click="remItem(x,$index);" > Remove</button>

$scope.remItem = function(x,index){
    $scope.emplist.splice(index,1);
}
```

It will help you !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<button ng-click="remItem(x);" > Remove</button>
```

and in controller

```
  $scope.remItem = function(item){
    var index = $scope.emplist.indexOf(item);
    $scope.emplist.splice(index,1);
  }
```

Comment: Inside the ng-repeat directive, special properties are exposed on the local scope including "$index" so you don't need to search the indexOf item in the remove function : <button ng-click="remItem($index);" > Remove</button>

Comment: You can't use `$index` if using filter in `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

**You can delete the row based on index **

```
 <button title="Remove" ng-click="removeFile($index)"></button>


$scope.removeFile = function (index) {
    if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to remove?")) {
        return;
    }
    $scope.emplist.splice(index, 1);}
```